# Module WYSIWYG with the 4.4.7 Ckeditor library stopped working

Tags: wysiwyg

What I got in Drupal 7:

```
WYSIWYG module 7.x-2.2

CKEditor library 4.4.7.3a35b3d
```

Changes I made:

**1.** This get's ckeditor library to work with WYSIWYG:

In .../modules/wysiwyg/editors/ckeditor.inc change line from function wysiwyg_ckeditor_version($editor)

```
if (preg_match('@version:\'(?:CKEditor )?([\d\.]+)(?:.+revision:\'([\d]+))?@', $line, $version)) {
```

to

```
if (preg_match('@version:\"(?:CKEditor )?([\d\.]+)(?:.+revision:\"([\d]+))?@', $line, $version)) {
```

This changes version number search from single quotes version: '4.0' to double quotes version "4.0"

This changed error in console log about jquery version.

**2.** In .. Wysywig .../modules/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.js change function

```
$('.wysiwyg', context).once('wysiwyg', function () {
```

to

```
 $('.wysiwyg:not(.processed)', context).addClass('processed').each(function() {
       if (!this.id || typeof Drupal.settings.wysiwyg.triggers[this.id] === 'undefined') {
         return;
       }
```

**3.** Iv'e cleared caches.

**4.** Added Full HTML format to /admin/config/content/formats

**5.** Added buttons at /admin/config/content/wysiwyg

**6.** Tried to "downgrade" to the 3.6.x version of CKEditor

**7.** Tried Ckeditor module https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor without wysiwyg module

**8.** Tired TinyMc library with wysiwyg

**9.** !Solution! need lines of kode at sites/all/templates/html.tpl.php to load wysiwyg.js .:

```
<?php print $page_top; ?>
<?php print $page; ?>
<?php print $page_bottom; ?>
```

Comment: Swap over to the [ckeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module, it is more up to date than the wysiwyg module. Plus if I'm not mistaken ckeditor has made it into Drupal 8 core so you will be better off using the same thing that Drupal 8 has chosen to bring into core.

Answer (score 0):

I would "downgrade" to the 3.6.x vrsion of CKEditor (such as CKEditor version 3.6.6.1.7696), since the [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module does not support the 4.x version yet ...). In this case, you may also want to experiment with the various '*cleanup and output*' options within `/admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile/your_txt_fmt/edit` (with '`your_txt_fmt`' the text format you're using, eg '`filtered_html`').

Another option is to switch to the [CKeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module (which is in core in D8 now ...), and no longer use the [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module in combination with the CKEditor library.

Comment: Up not worked

6. "downgrade" to the 3.6.x vrsion of CKEditor
7. Ckeditor module https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor
8. Tiny Mc with wysiwyg

Maybe i need ad smthing in template.tpl.php, page.tpl.php or node.tpl.php ?